# .DBC (FoxPro DBF) > FoxPro ODBC Driver > MIDDLEWARE > SaaS

Tags: migration, odbc, foxpro, visual-foxpro

I've been searching for Visual FoxPro ODBC Driver and finally found it. I am using a middleware to connect a .DBC (foxpro) > MIDDLEWARE > SaaS. I see from postings on MSDN that Microsoft suggests using OLEDB instead of ODBC, however I'm trying to interface a data source with an application that connects to data sources using ODBC connections. Would this be possible?